# Sqlite3 - выводит ошибку SQLITE_MISUSE

Tags: sqlite3, c++

Учусь писать ОО под на С++ для работы с sqlite3. Когда делаю все без ООП - все нормально. Но когда пишу используя классы - выводит ошибку при выполнении запроса но не при открытии БД.

Вот код:

SQL.h:

```
    class SQL { public:
    SQL();
    ~SQL();

    int openConnect(sqlite3 *pDB, const char db_name[]);
    void closeConnect(sqlite3 *pDB);
    int prepareQuery(sqlite3 *pDB, const char *zSql, int nByte = -1, sqlite3_stmt **ppSTMT = 0, const char
**pzTail = 0);
    int step(sqlite3_stmt *pSTMT);

};
```

SQL.cpp:

```
    int SQL::openConnect(sqlite3 *pDB, const char db_name[]) {
    return sqlite3_open(db_name, &pDB);
}

void SQL::closeConnect(sqlite3 *pDB) {
    sqlite3_close(pDB);
}

int SQL::prepareQuery(sqlite3 *pDB, const char *zSql, int nByte, sqlite3_stmt **ppSTMT, const char **pzTail) {
    return sqlite3_prepare(pDB, zSql, nByte, ppSTMT, pzTail);
}

int SQL::step(sqlite3_stmt *pSTMT) {
    return sqlite3_step(pSTMT);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{

    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    char db_name[] = "just_db.sqlite";
    const char *db_query = "insert into `user` values ('hey');";

    SQL *sql;

    rc = sql->openConnect(db, db_name);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "Erro: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    }

    std::cout << rc << std::endl;

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    rc = sql->prepareQuery(db, db_query, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
        std::cout << "Some error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    }

    std::cout << rc << std::endl;

    rc = sql->step(statement);

    if (rc == SQLITE_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "SOME ERROR: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    }

    std::cout << rc << std::endl;

    sql->closeConnect(db);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы: `sqlite3_open()` принимает указатель на указатель. По этому нужно изменить

```
int openConnect(sqlite3 *pDB, const char db_name[])
```

на

```
int openConnect(sqlite3 *&pDB, const char db_name[]);
```